# Android SDK file not found: adb - but visible in which adb

Tags: flutter, android-sdk-tools

Running `flutter doctor` gives error:

```
Android SDK file not found: adb.
```

I've installed `Android SDK Platform-Tools` via Android Studio and `adb` tool is available in `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools` (double platform-tools is correct location, added to PATH). Running `which adb` in terminal correctly prints `adb` location.

Flutter version: `1.12.13+hotfix.8`

How to show flutter `adb` location?

Comment: if u are using Mac OS Catalina, switching between bash to zsh, need to change all paths like flutter path, android sdk path. Have u checked this ?

Comment: I am using Catalina, but it's a fresh system and only zsh is in use

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since a recent Android SDK upgrade ADB has moved from `/Android/sdk/platform-tools` to `/Android/sdk/platform-tools/platform-tools`. A workaround to fix this issue in the meantime is to move `adb` from `/platform-tools/platform-tools/` up to `/platform-tools`.